# Create an href that has the same post type

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type named "*episodes*". I also have created a template for this custom post type called "*single-episodes*" when I get the template from "inc/episodios.php" it looks like this ...

```
get_header();
// Get template part
get_template_part('inc/episodios');
get_footer();
```

After that duplicate "*episidios.php*" and rename "*episodios-see.php*" with some modifications, both templates have the same custom post type called "*episodes*". I want create a link from *episidios.php* to *episodios-see.php*. For example:

```
<a href="link to episodios-see.php" class="myButton"> watch episodes </a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I tried editing your question, it is ***very*** unclear with what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain your question more clearly next time? Maybe look if the current readability is okay as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="myButton"> watch episodes </a>`

This will link to each single-episode from inside the loop